# CSS transition width not working with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, react-transition-group

Layout:

```
<div style={{ flex:1 }}>
    <div className="sideBarContainer">
         <div className="sideBar">
         <div className="sideBarExtra"> <--- conditional
    </div>
    <div className="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sideBarContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.sideBar {
    height: 100vh;
    min-width: 64px;
    z-index: 99;
}
.content {
    flex: 1;
    transition: width .3s linear;
}
```

sideBarExtra conditionally renders using the react-tranisition-group CSSTransitionGroup component.

The sideBarExtra will slide in smoothly from left to right when it is rendered, and slide out right to left when it is removed.

The content div does not transition smoothly when sideBarExtra is added, it jumps to its spots.

**Expected behaviour:** content to smoothly slide to it's new width.

In the console dev tools I can see the content width being changed, but no transition animation is happening.

Comment: Are we somehow missing that React.js takes className instead of class to take in styles?

Comment: I just rewrote the code for readability here, I didn't want to paste in all the components since they're multiple files. The code is using className but I'll edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.sideBarContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}
.sideBar {
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
    min-width: 64px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.content {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
    transition: width .3s linear;
}
.content:hover {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
    <div class="sideBarContainer">
         <div class="sideBar">
         <div class="sideBarExtra"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Hover me</div>
</div>
```

You can change the instant

```
.content {
    flex: 1;
    transition: width: .3s linear;
}
```

to

```
.content {
    flex: 1;
    transition: width .3s linear;
}
```

the transition does not take any **:** Colon here the above code

**Answer 2**

You can also set animation for flex property here the example:

```css
.sideBarContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}
.sideBar {
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
    min-width: 64px;
    z-index: 99;
    flex: 2;
    transition: flex .3s linear;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
    height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
    transition: flex .3s linear;
}
.sideBarContainer:hover .sideBar { 
  flex: 1;
}
.sideBarContainer:hover .content {
  flex: 2 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
    <div class="sideBarContainer">
         <div class="sideBar">
         <div class="sideBarExtra"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Hover me</div>
</div>
```